# RubyGems doesn't work at all on Windows 7 because of SSL Error

Tags: ruby, ssl, rubygems

I've installed RubyInstaller on Windows 7 but I couldn't install any gem because of SSL Error I get:

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

I tried to solve it via [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88) but I don't have **ssl_certs** directory. I tried to change environment variable too, but still nothing.

Comment: No you must have been here `C:\Ruby23\lib\ruby\2.3.0\rubygems\ssl_certs` Please check that out. But the problem is not that, they are asking us to put the `AddTrustExternalCARoot-2048.pem.` file inside that folder, but the problem is, It's available from Ruby 2.1.6, It has been working fine all these days, it's stopped working few weeks ago and started throwing this error. I have tried installed watir gem the same problem is popping up.

Comment: dont wanna troll, but working on windows with ruby is swimming upstream... Why not install Ubuntu and have everything working ?

Comment: @LukaszMuzyka I have been using Ruby in windows for past six years, I haven't faced any problem so far. Everything goes fine.

Comment: @LukaszMuzyka I'm not using Windows as primary OS since 2013, friend had issue on his laptop (inexperienced user, never heard about Linux).

Comment: @Gopal - sure if it works for you. Im sure you also run your production apps in windows environment too.

Comment: @LukaszMuzyka Yes, we are using windows.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar SSL Errors (on Windows 7) and went through all the recommended steps of adding a .pem file with no luck. Finally resolved this by downloading the lastest [RubyGems](http://rubyjems.org/pages/download) and followed the manual, pre-gem approach, for installation. Hope someone finds this helpful.